# How get a text element from an xpath expression in Selenium?

Tags: java, xpath

When Selenium navigates through web pages I want to save some of the text from that web pages. I use Selenium with Java. So is there a way to extract from that web pages the text having a specific xpath?

Answer (score 0):

```
selenium.getText("//div[@id='debugState']");
```

Visit, http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getText%28java.lang.String%29